# Kestrel :: Bind to multiple HTTP and HTTPS urls through appsettings.json

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, c#-5.0, kestrel-http-server, kestrel

I have a ASP.NET Core service build in .Net 5 which uses Kestrel as edge server. The service needs to listen on multiple domains on HTTP protocol - e.g. `http://foo:12912` & `http://bar:12912` and HTTPS protocol like `http://foo:443` & `http://bar:443`.

I know we can do with `UseUrls` in `Program.cs`.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                webBuilder.UseUrls("http://foo:12912", "http://bar:12912");
            });
}
```

However - given that Kestel has evolved so much - there should be a way to configure this from json config itself. All config examples that I could find only do for a single url like

```
"Kestrel": {
  "EndPoints": {
    "Http": {
      "Url": "http://foo:12912"
    },
    "Https": {
      "Url": "https://foo:443"
    }
  }
}
```

The property name is also `url` and not `urls` so my assumption is that it only supports single url and not multiple. Is my expectation correct or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

In development you can use the launchSettings.json like this:

```
"WebApplication1": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
```

Notice that the applicationUrl takes a list separated by semicolons.

In production usually kestrel would be fronted by a reverse proxy.

Like NGINX configured as a reverse proxy which would handle the SSL and the kestrel would not need to expose ssl ports since all the security **should** be handled by the actual webserver and **not** by kestrel.

Kestrel is not designed to be **exposed** to the internet. But it is actually a minimalistic wrapper for a web application.

That being said....
However there is way to do what you want.

Way 1 use multiple endpoints:
Notice you can add many endpoints with different json keys.

```
 {
  "Kestrel": {
    "Endpoints": {
      "Http": {
        "Url": "http://localhost:5000"
      },
      "HttpsInlineCertFile": {
        "Url": "https://localhost:5001",
        "Certificate": {
          "Path": "<path to .pfx file>",
          "Password": "<certificate password>"
        }
      },
      "HttpsInlineCertAndKeyFile": {
        "Url": "https://localhost:5002",
        "Certificate": {
          "Path": "<path to .pem/.crt file>",
          "KeyPath": "<path to .key file>",
          "Password": "<certificate password>"
        }
      },
      "HttpsInlineCertStore": {
        "Url": "https://localhost:5003",
        "Certificate": {
          "Subject": "<subject; required>",
          "Store": "<certificate store; required>",
          "Location": "<location; defaults to CurrentUser>",
          "AllowInvalid": "<true or false; defaults to false>"
        }
      },
      "HttpsDefaultCert": {
        "Url": "https://localhost:5004"
      }
    },
    "Certificates": {
      "Default": {
        "Path": "<path to .pfx file>",
        "Password": "<certificate password>"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Way 2 use the ASPNETCORE_URLS or DOTNET_URLS environment variables and assign a semicolon separated list of urls.

Way 3 set the "urls" key in the appsettings.json whic also uses a semicolon separated list of urls.

```
{
  "Urls": "http://localhost:9999;https://someotherdomain.com"  
}
```

Further documentation and limitations of each method are here

[Configure endpoints for the ASP.NET Core Kestrel web server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: Thanks. For way 3 - could you post the whole config - Urls along with Kestrel tag?

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal way 3 is not inside the kestrel tag. its just at the root of the appsettings.json and it follows the same pattern of semicolon separated list of urls.  I added another url so you can see what i mean

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you just need to put semicolons in your Url section
from below is excerpt from https://andrewlock.net/5-ways-to-set-the-urls-for-an-aspnetcore-app/

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false, 
    "anonymousAuthentication": true, 
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:38327",
      "sslPort": 44310
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "TestApp": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```